# Week of the Month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME= GETDATE()

SELECT  DATEDIFF(WEEK,
                 DATEADD(WEEK,
                         DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,
                                  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0)),
                         0), @date - 1) + 1
```

What is purpose of 0 as a parameter in the `datediff()` function?

Comment: This is the old fashioned way to get the date at the beginning of the month.

Comment: Before ask search in the google first

Comment: Another SQL question with a shouting title? What is this?!

Comment: hi sir can you give me example bcoz i just stated to learn sql please help me

Answer (score 1):

The specific answer to your question is that the `0` is just a way to get the beginning of the month:

```
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)
```

This is one method to do this in SQL Server, because it does not offer a "date truncate" function.  I prefer:

```
dateadd(day, 1 - day(@date), @date)
```

(Although admittedly this is a wee bit more complicated if `@date` has a time component.)

However, a much simpler way to do this is:

```
select (day(@date) - 1) / 7) as week_of_month
```

Answer (score 0):

Below gets the number of months from a reference point

```
datediff(month, 0, @date)
```

Then it is used to add to the reference date back to reach the first day of the month

dateadd(month, 
        datediff(month, 0, @date),
        0)

So it is used to find the first day of the current month

declare @date datetime = getdate()

```
select 
    getdate(),
    datediff(month, 0, @date),
    dateadd(month, 
            datediff(month, 0, @date),
            0)
```

[image]